# How to manually shutdown embedded Tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to implement a graceful shutdown sequence for my Spring Boot application. For that I registered a custom shutdown hook with Runtime and disabled the one provided by Spring (SpringApplication.setRegisterShutdownHook(false)). From this custom shutdown hook I first would like to pause embedded Tomcat or the connectors and some other schedulers after which I manually invoke applicationContext.close() to shutdown the rest of the Spring application.

What is the best way to get access to the embedded Tomcat instance? I was fiddling around with TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory but this does not seem to give me access to default connectors or EmbeddedServletContainer which has a stop method.

Comment: The Spring shutdown hook does a graceful shutdown on the container. Is it not working for you?

Comment: I need more control in the sequence of how things are shutdown. First the schedulers etc need to shutdown, after that the rest of the application context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `EmbeddedServletContainer` from the `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext` (just inject that) and downcast it.